# How to get machine name/ip address of a SQL query from which that was run using sql id in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the sql id of a query. Now I want to get the machine name and IP of the machine from which this query was run.

I have already checked the sql id in V$SESSION and V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY but didn't get any results.

I am able to find the sql id in v$sql and LAST_LOAD_TIME is today(7 July 2016).

```
select LAST_LOAD_TIME from v$sql where SQL_ID='0jf4618m2u7aw' order by LAST_LOAD_TIME desc;
2016-07-04/17:26:02
2016-07-04/17:26:02


select * from V$SESSION where SQL_ID='0jf4618m2u7aw';
no rows selected

select * from V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY where SQL_ID='0jf4618m2u7aw';
no rows selected
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options...

If it is an active session/process, you can use v$session and v$process:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        MACHINE,
        UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS(MACHINE) AS IP_ADDR
FROM    V$SESSION S,
        V$PROCESS P
WHERE   S.PADDR = P.ADDR
AND     S.SQL_ID = '0jf4618m2u7aw';
```

If you want a historical view, the DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY might be your friend:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        MACHINE,
        UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS(MACHINE) AS IP_ADDR
FROM    DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY DHASH
WHERE   DHASH.SQL_ID = '0jf4618m2u7aw'
AND     DHASH.SQL_EXEC_START > TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using second query but getting error "Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MACHINE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:"

Comment: The column is definitely available in 11gr2. It is not available in 10g. Your question is tagged 11g. I am wondering if you are using 10g or if you are using 11gr1 and it wasn't available until 11gr2. Can you do, `select  version from v$instance`

Comment: yes, you are right. I am running query in 11gr1. Can you please help how i can i do this in 11gr1?